# undefined method `Include' for ImageUploader:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, carrierwave

I'm currently setting up Active_Admin so the user can create an article and can upload a picture to illustrate it, using Carrier Wave (way too much problems with PaperClip).
Everything is working fine until I add my 'article.rb' inside `app/admin`

I now can't launch the server without getting the following error: `undefined method`Include' for ImageUploader:Class (NoMethodError)`, and the error doesn't show up when I delete my file.

Here is my uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  Include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [250, 0]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

This is the article.rb file inside my admin folder

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do
  form_for @article, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    f.inputs "Article" do
      f.input :titre
      f.input :contenu
      f.input :image, :as => :file
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

And this is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#base
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

#Gems installed after

#Contacts
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mail'

#Admin
gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.8.rc3'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'formtastic', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'carrierwave', '>= 1.0.0.beta', '< 2.0'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
```

The controller contains nothing useful since it's only there to display the article.

I think the error is linked to miniMagick since this is the only "include" in my whole project, but still, I need to resize some pictures...

Any help welcomed

Comment: You want `include` i.e. lowercase as in the comment above the line causing the error

Comment: try this, include CarrierWave::RMagick  OR include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

Comment: Thank you @j-dexx, it worked fine!! You guys are on fire!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
```

OR

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
```

Comment: This made me have the error "Undefined method 'OR'"

Comment: Dude, Its a option to you not rails application, I'm telling you to use one of then not the whole line.

Comment: ok sorry, I upvoted your answer as an apology, but it wasn't really explicit, my bad ^^'

Comment: If your issue is solved, please accept the answer so that it help someone else.